# connecting mongodb model to apollo-server 2.0

Tags: mongodb, graphql, apollo-server

I am following a tutorial which uses mongo database with graphql, currently the tutor uses apollo-server v1 but I am using apollo-server v2, the problem I'm having is where do i make the connection of my models to graphql,

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config({ path: "variables.env" });
const Recipe = require("./models/Recipe");
const User = require("./models/User");

// Bring in GraphQL-Express middleware
const { graphiqlExpress, graphqlExpress } = require("apollo-server-express");
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require("graphql-tools");

const { typeDefs } = require("./schema");
const { resolvers } = require("./resolvers");

// Create schema
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

// Connects to database
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
  .then(() => console.log("DB connected"))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

// Initializes application
const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  credentials: true
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Create GraphiQL application
app.use("/graphiql", graphiqlExpress({ endpointURL: "/graphql" }));

// Connect schemas with GraphQL
app.use(
  "/graphql",
  bodyParser.json(),
  graphqlExpress({
    schema,
    context: {
      Recipe,
      User
    }
  })
);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4444;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on PORT ${PORT}`);
});
```

so in apollo-server v1 you pass in your mongo schema (models) in graphqlExpress

```
 Connect schemas with GraphQL
    app.use(
      "/graphql",
      bodyParser.json(),
      graphqlExpress({
        schema,
        context: {
          Recipe,
          User
        }
      })
    );
```

but in v2 you no longer use graphqlExpress function,

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/migration-two-dot.html

so how/where do i pass in my database models to?

currently I have this

```
const express = require ('express')
const mongoose = require ('mongoose')
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');

require('dotenv').config({path: 'variables.env'})

// mongo schemas/models
const Recipe = require('./models/Recipe')
const User = require('./models/User')

//Graphql schema
const {typeDefs} = require('./schema')
const {resolvers} = require('./resolvers')

// connects to database
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {useNewUrlParser: true} )
.then(()=> console.log('DB connected'))
.catch(error => console.log(error))

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4444;

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

const app = express();
server.applyMiddleware({ app });

app.listen({ port: PORT }, () =>
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:${PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be exactly like you were before, you need to add the `context` function onto your ApolloServer init:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: ({ req }) => ({
    Recipe,
    User
  })
});
```

Comment: thank you very much that fixed it, now im getting an error when i request back an id, would i need to JSON.stingify the models? as the id is 'ObjectID' and if so would i need to do it in the resolver or can i do it in the context? with appollo server v1, you could use bodyparser like so "app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({ schema: myGraphQLSchema }));"  but for v2 its already built in as far as i can tell in the docs? [link] (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/migration-two-dot.html#simple-use) in server.applyMiddleware({ app }); but its not working for me?

Comment: ive set server.applyMiddleware({ app, bodyParserConfig:true }); but it still does not work?

Answer (score 0):

This [example](https://github.com/believer/movies-graphql-postgres) works perfect with PG, if you are using Mongo, just replace pg calls with mongoose and you should be good to go.